# Is it true that every Chinese word can also be a Japanese word?

Tags: chinese, loanwords

I have heard that Japanese has the largest number of words of any language because every Chinese word can also be a Japanese word. Is there any truth to this statement?

Comment: @Patricker: I think you might be confused over the potentiality of every Chinese **character** to be used in Japanese, but most Chinese words are actually compounds of two or more characters.

Comment: Besides, English has the most words of any language.

Comment: @Louis i actually doubt it.. but where did you get that info from?

Comment: @Pacerier, please see this: http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/englishmostwords

Out of curiosity, why do you doubt it? Or rather, which language did you suspect has the most?

Comment: @Louis because japanese imports, and is still importing words from english. english 230k (http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/93) japanese 600k (http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081019181001AAkrNoE) of course.. this is very subjective

Comment: @Pacerier, Shogakukan's dictionary is so large because it aims to be so complete, including items that the OED does not, such as words not currently in use. It also has 方言, and 四字熟語. I won't argue that those aren't words, but I'm just pointing out you won't find something like "college education" (大学教育). The OED has around 600,000 words, about 230K with full entries. It would have 20% more if it included archaic words. 750K if it included distinct senses (perhaps similar to Shogakukan's 同訓異字 and 異字同訓). I can only imagine how many there would be included all of the words created by science.

Comment: @Louis problem is that every single word created by science will map 1 to 1 (at least most of them you can say) to every language wouldn't it? (So shouldn't it be safe to exclude words created by science from both languages when doing counting?)

Comment: This question seems rediculous to me. No language's vocabulary is a subset of another.

Comment: @hippietrail, you meant "most *Japanese* words" instead of "most Chinese words", didn't you?

Comment: @jarmanso7: No I meant "most *Chinese words*". Most Chinese words are 2-character words but Japanese words vary a lot more. Probably most Sino-Japanese words are still 2- character words though. OP seemed not to distinguish Chinese words from Chinese characters. While it's probably true that every Chinese character would be a valid character in Japanese, it doesn't follow that every Chinese character would work alone as a Japanese word or that every Chinese 2-character or bigger word would work as a Japanese word.

Comment: @hippietrail got it, thank you! I don't know any Chinese but was under the impression that most Chinese words are made of one character, not two. I agree with your statements.

Comment: @jarmanso7: No worries. Most people who haven't dug into Chinese think so. Classical Chinese did actually work that way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although it's true that there are a very, *very* large number of kanji compounds imported from Chinese to Japanese, it's not as direct as that statement. There are Chinese words that don't exist in Japanese, and many Chinese Kanji have different meanings or pronunciations, as well as occasionally being written slightly differently. These differences are particularly profound in words with grammatical significance:

- 你 (cn: nei5; jp: ni, ji, nanji) - Chinese for 'you'. Very common in Chinese, rare in Japanese (other words are used instead)
- 我 (cn: ngo5; jp: wa, ware) - Chinese for 'me'. In Japanese carries a connotation of referring to yourself as a representative of a larger group, and is therefore somewhat uncommon.
- 的 (cn: dik1; jp: teki) - Chinese possessive particle; has a function similar to の in Japanese. In Japanese, this is a suffix meaning 'the essence of'. You see this used in, eg, 攻撃的 or 積極的, but it is not used the same way as in Chinese at all.

There are also differences in usage patterns for modern inventions - eg, Chinese uses 电脑 for 'computer', but in Japanese the katakana コンピューター is more common.

As for whether there are more words in Japanese than other languages, I couldn't say. I would suspect, though, that if you looked at the set of *commonly used* words, it would be about the same; if you were to include classical words, loanwords, and rarely used native equivalents for loanwords, you might see a bit more than the average language.

Comment: 电脑 is computer，计算机 is calculator (or 計算機 if you're in HongKong, Taiwan)

Comment: @repecmps 计算机 can mean both calculator AND computer actually

Comment: @Ken: The translation 计算机 = computer is there because 30 years ago a calculator was indeed a computer. Nowadays it is just a "counting machine" or calculator whereas 电脑 is the "electronic brain" or computer :)

Comment: @repecmps Actually 计算机 still means computer in modern usage, this is from my experience with speaking with native speakers AND see this article http://baike.baidu.com/view/3314.htm (although i'm not a native speaker myself so I can't really say which one is more popular, but I can say they are both used)

Comment: As I said, in dictionaries it is to indicate that during a time a calculator was a computer. **现代**计算机是一种能快速而高效地完成信息处理的数字化电子设备. You have remnants of these times in words like micro-computer (which is not very recent either) = 微型计算机 but  计算机 alone is nowadays a calculator. 计算机 is seen as computer in the sense it "computes numbers". Chinese who want to talk about computers will say 电脑 or 笔记本. When my wife asks me 计算机给我, I don't give her the computer but a calculator and when she forgot how to find calc.exe she asks: 计算机怎么打开？ </off topic>

Comment: @repecmps Well, seems like that Wikipedia and Baidu Baike disagrees with you I guess, there's nothing much to say other than that.

Comment: These definition websites use dictionaries, so the "computer" meaning is there. Not 1 Chinese in mainland will say:  计算机 for computer. When you search for 计算机 in baidu images you get a calculator (or very old computers which proves my point above), when you search for it in an online store, they give you calculators. So wikipedia and baidu don't disagree, they just don't mention that 计算机 is an old term for "numbers computing machine" and that a less old term for personal computer but still not used nowadays is 微型计算机. (never 计算机 alone) I cannot be clearer to a non Chinese speaker.

Comment: http://image.baidu.com/i?ct=201326592&cl=2&lm=-1&tn=baiduimage&istype=2&fm=index&pv=&z=0&sf=0&word=%BC%C6%CB%E3%BB%FA&s=0#pn=0 and http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%E8%AE%A1%E7%AE%97%E6%9C%BA&oe=utf-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&hl=ja&tab=wi&biw=1600&bih=750 (I did exactly what you said, search on baidu/google images and there are images of modern computers, so far still disagreeing with your position that not 1 Chinese in mainland doesn't say 计算机 for computer,there are images of calculators so I'm not saying it does NOT mean calculator)

Comment: google japan: hl=ja (so no comment). for baidu images I'm still looking for modern computers :) (to be honest I've seen 1 almost modern in a list of 100 results, others were calculators and old computers > 30 years) Oh and 计算器 is the exact word for calculator but that doesn't change the fact that 计算机 is old or used in a specialized context and that people will give me a calculator if I ask for a 计算机

Comment: And to close the debate once and for all: http://s.taobao.com/search?q=%BC%C6%CB%E3%BB%FA&keyword=&commend=all&ssid=s5-e&search_type=item&atype=&tracelog=&sourceId=tb.index Thanks for your time :D

Comment: I'm not saying 计算机 isn't used more often, but it is used to refer to computers by SOME Chinese people. Otherwise you would not have see images of nvidia on baidu images. 计算机 is not a word in Japanese try it on google hk you'll see very similar result. http://www.google.com.hk/search?tbm=isch&hl=zh-CN&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=750&q=%E8%AE%A1%E7%AE%97%E6%9C%BA&btnG=%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2%E5%9B%BE%E7%89%87&gbv=2&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=

Comment: Yes, I can agree with you on this point (finally). If you go to a specialized computer shop asking for 计算机, they will give you a computer. (although they will refer to it as 电脑 later during the conversation and write 笔记本 or 微型计算机 on the bill) edit: hmmm, reading your first comment it looks like I didn't get exactly what you were saying.

Comment: @KenLi repecmps (oh I can't have two @'s) Interesting discussion. As a native Chinese speaker living near/in Beijing from the time I was born, this is first time I heard 计算机 can be used for calculator. Calculator is called 计算器. 计算机 and 电脑 are almost equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

The *Chinese* calligraphy came to Japan approximately 1,500~2,000 years ago, so I'd argue that that statement goes the other way: Chinese people can read many Japanese words and grasp quickly what they mean.

Chinese, on the other hand, uses many, many kanji that are not found in Japanese's ~2,000 常用漢字 *joyo-kanji* taught in the education system.  So, I don't think it's true that Japanese people, without proper study, can read Chinese words, nor does it mean that for that reason Japanese has so many words.

You are correct in noting that Japanese does have a lot of words because various nuances can be formed by combining slightly different kanji with similar meanings.  When I was learning about 状態, I was very frustrated to find that 実態, 事態, 状況, 実況, and 事情 all more-or-less translated as "circumstances" or "situation" in my dictionary at the time.

Soapbox: that's why learning kanji can be good for your vocabulary - it becomes about understanding the nuance of the kanji, not rote memorization of a bunch of words.

Answer (score 4):

Not EVERY Chinese word. But lots and lots of them. China has always been the dominant culture in that area, so there are lots of Sino-Korean, Sino-Vietnamese and Sino-Japanese words. Writing was imported from China and later adapted for Japanese. When the Dutch brought over all of their science and medicine books, all of terms that didn't exist in Japanese were translated using Sino-Japanese words.

Slowly katakana English is taking over, however, meaning that there are a huge number of words with both English and Chinese counterparts. Even if Japanese doesn't have the biggest vocabulary in the world (remember diglossia in Arabic societies, languages with morphology so complicated that it denies all attempts to count words, etc.) it still is huge.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know that languages will evolve over time. Parts of the Japanese language was largely influenced by classical Chinese, so a lot of Japanese words you see will make sense in Chinese and vice versa. However Japanese and Chinese are different language so even if they share similar volcabulary they are not simliar grammatically wise.

Some words in Japanese means the same thing in Chinese and Japanese. This is the case about 75% of the time. Then there are cases where Japanese words make sense in Chinese, but Chinese people tend to not use them. For example the word 上手 means to be skilled at something. If you say that in Chinese people will (probably) understand you but it's not natural because it's like saying "grand fries" in English rather than "large fries"

Then there are cases where Japanese words means something completely different in Chinese. For example 勉強 means to study in Japanese, but in Chinese it means reluctance.

Answer (score 2):

This actually came up in class awhile back and our sensei (native speaker) answered roughly as follows:

> A Japanese person going to China will recognize enough kanji to be able to get around and maybe get the gist of a newspaper article but since Japanese uses a limited subset of the sinographs, they will not be able to read everything they see and will also encounter problems in regards to interpenetration due to the changes since when they were first introduced. Likewise, Chinese person will recognize enough kanji that they can also get around if they visit Japan, but will encounter the same problems with interpretation and would also need to learn the hiragana and katakana.

Couple this with the differences in grammar (i.e. verb-final vs. subject-verb-object) and the meaning of a sentence can also be lost even if you have a rough idea as to what the kanji mean.

Answer (score -1):

On an practical level, the other answers are correct.

However, it is *technically* (almost) true that "any Chinese word is also a Japanese word", because (almost*) all Chinese characters can be *theoretically* used as kanji and have an onyomi (音読み, sino-Japanese pronunciation).

The most comprehensive Kanji dictionary, the [Dai Kan-Wa Jiten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dai_Kan-Wa_Jiten) has around 50000 characters—similar in number to the largest Chinese hanzi dictionaries.

To be clear, "any Chinese word can be used as a Japanese word" is true only in a pedantic sense.  It is almost like saying "any Latin word is an English word".

See also: [naruto's answer to this related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52145/can-any-han-character-kanji-be-used-as-part-of-the-japanese-writting-system?rq=1)

---

*of course, there are also Chinese characters (Hanzi) that have *never* been used in Japanese, so don't have a well-defined onyomi, just like there are Japanese kokuji (国字) that have never been used in Chinese and therefore have no pinyin pronunciation.

Comment: What makes a word "Japanese"? I don't think that because you can write any given Chinese word in the corresponding Japanese kanji and onyomi it automatically turns it into a Japanese word. That's an assumption I am not willing to make. To me, your statement is equivalent to saying "kuruma" and "tomodachi" are English words, because we have a way to spell them using the alphabet.

Comment: @jarmanso7 "kuruma" and "tomodachi" CAN be made into English words, if you *define* them, and IF you have a good reason to use them instead of "car" and "friend".  On the other hand, you cannot use 車 and 友達 in an English text because it would be ridiculous to expect the average reader to be able to read them.  That's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: the answer to this question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52145/can-any-han-character-kanji-be-used-as-part-of-the-japanese-writting-system?rq=1 sums it up nicely

Comment: You are answering and quoting a very nice answer to a different question (can any kanji be used as part of the Japanese *writting system*?). I don't get your point, of course "kuruma" can be made into an English word, and so can "hihilupipo" (I've just invented the term on the fly). What's your point?

Comment: As you acknowledge in the beginning of your post, you are not giving an answer from a practical standpoint, the problem is that what you claim is technically *not* true, either, or at least it is up to debate. The fact that any word can be made into a word in Japanese, or English, doesn't equate to that word being Japanese or English in the first place, at least until it has been assimilated or integrated. See [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english)

Comment: And, to ilustrate what I mean, you can come to any average native English speaker and tell them "kuruma". Probably they won't get it, unless they know Japanese. Why? because "kuruma" is not an English word.

Comment: @jarmanso7 To be clear, I am *not* claiming that the perspective I present here is the only correct one.  I am mainly trying to present an alternative interpretation of this question to that of the other answers here.  In any case, I made it clear in the answer that i was answering the question in a "technical" sense.

Comment: Anyways, my main point (which, I admit, was not addressed in my earlier reply to your kuruma/tomodachi example) is that "all chinese characters", or at least the tens of thousands of characters that appear in the Dai Kan-Wa Jiten, are part of the Japanese lexicon, because they show up in a *Japanese* dictionary with an official *Japanese* pronounciation

Comment: I agree completely with your point. But characters are not words.

Comment: Ok, so character=/= word, but I'm not sure what your point is here.  Also I would argue that the concept of "word" is hard to apply to east asian languages, which emphasize morphemes (=characters) more than words.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148284/discussion-between-jarmanso7-and-aqualone).